# Informatica powercenter always can't read the file properly. All data always appears in one column

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have problem with informatica powercenter. When i want to import data from flat file csv, all datas always appear in one column. I need to edit the file first, and set define name in excel then informatica can read all data properly. How to read the data properly in powercenter without doing define name first in excel?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure,

1. You're reading file definition as delimited. Here is a file wizard where you can define it as delimited.
2. while reading set it so it reads col name from first row.
3. And then read from second row.
   You can check this img.
   https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-enDSMKLYyRY/UXADBtNE8WI/AAAAAAAAAu8/oVfr6IsAl8Y/s1600/8.jpg

If you set above properties up, infa should be able to read definition properly and you dont have to set col name or datatype.